# Is there any functional difference between array_upper and array_length?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

The postgres docs on these 2 array functions are pretty weak.

I've tried both functions a few different ways and they seem to return the same results.

```
SELECT array_length(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 1);
SELECT array_upper(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 1);

SELECT array_length(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 2);
SELECT array_upper(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 2);
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a difference. PostgreSQL array subscripts start at one by default but [they don't have to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html):

> By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of `n` elements starts with `array[1]` and ends with `array[n]`.
>   [...]
>   Subscripted assignment allows creation of arrays that do not use one-based subscripts. For example one might assign to `myarray[-2:7]` to create an array with subscript values from `-2 to 7`.
>   [...]
>   By default, the lower bound index value of an array's dimensions is set to one. To represent arrays with other lower bounds, the array subscript ranges can be specified explicitly before writing the array contents.

In general, you need to use [`array_lower` and `array_upper`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead of assuming that the array will start at `1` and end at `array_length(a, n)`.

Comment: Thanks- this is great. So it seems like this statement is true: `array_length` returns the absolute value of array elements regardless of the start/end value of the array?

Comment: `array_length` returns "the length of the requested array dimension" so it doesn't care about where the array start and ends, only how many entries it has.